# Webscraper will not iterate

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

f = urlopen("http://www.groupon.co.uk/").read()

bs = BeautifulSoup(f)

for tag in bs.find_all('ul', {'id': 'jCitiesSelectBox'}):
    print tag.li['onclick']
```

only prints out first tag, does not print out all tags in jCitiesSelectBox and I can't see why.

Answer (score 0):

you probably have the selectors backwards.  Only one tag per document is permitted to have a particular `id`.  What you've specified is "find the tag with `id="jCitiesSelectBox`, only if it's in a `<ul>` tag".

Edit:

What you probably want is to find all of the `<li>` tags inside the tag with `id="jCitiesSelectBox"`, something like:

```
cities_list = bs.find('ul', {'id': 'jCitiesSelectBox'})
for tag in cities_list.find_all('li'):
    print tag['onclick']
```

(not tested)

Comment: That returns nothing. Basically jCitiesSelectBox is the id of the div, in which there is the entire list I want to scrape

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

f = urlopen("http://www.groupon.co.uk/").read()

bs = BeautifulSoup(f)

f = urlopen("http://www.groupon.co.uk/").read()

bs = soup(f)

tags = bs.findAll('ul', attrs={'id' : 'jCitiesSelectBox'})
for tag in tags:
    lip = tag.findAll('li')
    for li in lip:
        print li['onclick']
```

Tested, works for me.